# Why my thread has been closed and locked?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

From [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150926191651/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/29/10146895.aspx?PageIndex=1)
It proves that what I've said here:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64245/vs2010-aka-very-slow-2010
is valid/constructive and over all true.  Funny but in the first link there are comments which are almost identical to what I've said in my second link provided.
I sometimes wonder about people who even though Microsoft itself admitts that Very Slow 2010 is slower than 2008 ([here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/03/10136696.aspx?PageIndex=3#comments)) yet, they still saying that on their machines Very Slow 2010 is working faster than VS2008?
So the question is: After reading what I've provided in links are you still saying that Very Slow 2010 performs better than VS2008

Comment: is nothing ... why you asking QUESTION here..if you are damn sure about your argues and dun want to listen othrs

Comment: I've cleaned up irrelevant comments and unlocked the post again. If the argument resumes, the post will be re-locked and possibly removed. Let's all keep it civil and constructive here. Thanks.

Comment: @Anna Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

The post was locked as the comments were getting out of hand. I've unlocked it now.

It doesn't help that you call Visual Studio 2010 "Very Slow 2010".

If you want it to be reopened, edit it to remove the highly subjective and <strike>potentially inflammatory</strike> pejorative language and then if the community votes it will be reopened.

Comment: @ChrisF I'm sorry but which part of my original Q is "potentially inflammatory"? And why did you've post "your piece" as an answer? In what way does it answer to my quesion? It should be comment if anything. -1

Comment: @There is nothing - calling it "Very Slow 2010" for a start.

Comment: @Chris I call it Very Slow because: first - it doesn't attack anyone personally, second - because it is very slow. How shall I call it if I want to indicate the speed it works with? (!Very Fast 2010)? Would that be better?

Comment: @There is nothing - no it would not. Simply call it "Visual Studio 2010" and then make your case about it being slow.

Comment: @ChrisF I think I stick to the Very Slow 2010 as it better reflects what it really is.

Comment: @There is nothing - in that case I'm not going to reopen the post. If other members of the community want to I won't stop them, but **as it is currently worded** the post is not constructive.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do - I expect, if that is your attitude, then @ChrisF will leave your question closed.